# allow user to tap label and then tap buttons to edit label.text?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface

So what I have right now i table with multiple cells. Each cell has two UIlabels. Underneath the table are a bunch of buttons with different int values. I want to allow the user to tap on a label and then tap on the buttons to change the text of the label to whatever buttons they press. Eg if they press buttons, "1","2","3" the label will display 6.

I think i managed to figure out how to find out which label has been touched, but I'm stuck afterwards as i can't figure out how to get the button pressing part to work. Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know which UILabel has been touched add a tap gesture to each label which triggers an action. In that actions store which label has been touched in e.g. a property.
For the buttons, just connect them to action methods (could also be a single one), inside these methods do your calculation and updated the label indicated by the property described above.